# Deploying Django to Heroku using ClearDB, version issue

Tags: mysql, django, heroku, cleardb

I keep getting this error, "NotSupportedError at /logs/ MySQL 5.7 or later is required (found 5.6.50)." Is this a problem with ClearDB?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem. Just as an idea I installed mysql into my virtual environment using `pip install mysql`. After running `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, it added MySQL to my requirements.txt and found that that when I pushed to heroku the problem disappeared. Hopefully that helps.